# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Medical Sciences Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **February 21, 2022** to bring in 2 more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 21, 2022, users can [nominate themselves](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On February 28, 2022, if there are 3 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on March 8, 2022 (or March 15, 2022, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Two people downvoted this. I don't know how to interpret such votes. They disagree with holding an election? If so, they might want to say what they propose instead. Otherwise, I have no idea what those votes mean.

Comment: @CareyGregory same I don't get it.